# Let $x=(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in a metric space $X$ having a convergent subsequene

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, proof-verification

Let $x=(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in a metric space $X$ having a convergent subsequene $x\sigma=(x_{\sigma_n})$ where $\sigma:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ is strictly increasing. Then $(x_n)$ is convergent.

> - **My attempt:** Let $(x\sigma)(n)\to l$ in $X.$ For $\epsilon>0~\exists~k\in\mathbb N$ such that $d(x(\sigma(n)),l)<\epsilon/2~\forall~n\ge k$ and $d(x(m),x(n))<\epsilon/2~\forall~m,n\ge k.$ Since $\sigma(n)\ge n~\forall~n$ it follows that $$d(x(\sigma(n)),x(n))<\epsilon/2~~\forall~n\ge k\\d(x(\sigma(n)),l)<\epsilon/2~\forall~n\ge k$$
>
> By triangular inequality, $d(x(n),l)<\epsilon~\forall~n\ge k.$ Hence Proved.

Am I correct?

Comment: It seems fine to me !

Comment: In the second line you want $d(x(\sigma(n)),l)$, not $d(x(\sigma(n))-l)$, but otherwise it’s correct.